# Setting -XdisableCastChecking to true

Tags: gwt

I need to set -XdisableCastChecking to true for building a GWT application (with Eclipse).

I know how to do it to compile the application but I'm not able to set -XdisableCastChecking to true for building the war file (I'm using a build.xml and file).

Does anybody know how to include this flag into the ant file?

Thank you in advance.
Alsila

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard build.xml generated with the [wepAppCreator](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools.html#webAppCreator), you should have at the top of your build.xml something like the block below. Modify the `gwt.args` line adding the arguments you want to pass to the gwt compiler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="myproject" default="build" basedir=".">
  <!-- Arguments to gwtc and devmode targets -->
  <property name="gwt.args" value="-XdisableCastChecking" />

[...]
```